# High speed CAN data processing without using heap memory

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I have a situation:

Basically there are 3 modules named as 'A','B','C'.
Each of the module has multithreading involved.

Module 'A' takes the high speed data (20ms) and send it . One of the thread of module 'B' picks up.

Module 'B' extracts the relevant data and do some bit manipulation activity and broadcast it, so that any one of the thread of module 'C' picks up and does its own activity .

Now the data suppose in module 'B' while processing requires some bit manipulation , when we are sending data a heap allocation is getting used for each of the CAN(CONTROLLER AREA NETWORK) data because each of the data will have its own memory, so every time the data(20ms) comes inside B module , creates a heap memory .  Because of which there is lot of heap usage.

I cant use local variable , because other module will have no idea of it.

I tried to use static/global also , but the demerit is  because the data is fast. By the time the static variable takes the data and passes to the function which will broadcast , the data might get updated with new value( and there can be data loss).

I cant use locking system also as each module will have different threads and context will not be the same .

Is there any way , I can avoid the use of dynamic memory allocation?

In case  someone doesn't understand it completely pl let me know , I will try to reframe the question again. Pardon me for my english

Comment: You might consider a memory pool and a custom allocator. Or you could allocate one big block in advance and then manage the memory yourself with "placement new". Of course these approaches come with the headaches of implementing and maintaining these complex but foundational systems yourself.

Comment: @metal Can you pl elaborate it a little , because what I am getting it is that . A pool of memory is taken once from the kernel and then its divided amongst each of the data separately (does that what you mean by custom allocator).

Comment: I'd suggest googling for "C++ custom allocator memory pool". The first link on that search for me was a [good one](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/memory-pool-allocators-with-jonathan-mueller). Check it out. Then if you have more specific questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: "high speed data (20ms)" feels not high speed ;) But your scenario description sounds weird. Simply processing some amount of data in that slow speed should never result in passing data around global vars between different threads...

Comment: If the objects being exchanged among your threads are all of consistent, known-in-advance size, then perhaps you can use an *object pool* instead of a more general memory pool with custom allocator.

Comment: Can someone explain what CAN means in this context (pun unintentional)?  It isn't an easy term to search for.

Comment: Most likely a Controller Area Network bus

Comment: Have you thought about using a _[circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)_?

Comment: @Clonk: thanks — that makes sense.

Comment: @metal Thanks for the link , I am going through the link , I will try to find the best possible way for implementing memory manager

Comment: @John Bollinger , Actually its not , so just to give a brief idea , these CAN data can be grouped together( 8 bit * no of signals ) or it may remain a single signal(8 bit) , or it can be broadcast signal(16 bit) no of bits shall be changing .

Comment: @Klaus , You must have worked with much more speed :) , but I am new into this industry and still learning . Thanks for view also , as I now know that 20ms is not very fast.

Comment: @SolomonSlow . In circular buffer , I think there might be data loss in case it becomes full as the processing is a bit slower than the frequency of incoming data

Comment: @VBurman, no matter what you do, you cannot very long accommodate situations where data arrive faster than they are processed, at least not without data loss.  With dynamic allocation at some level you could adapt to traffic spikes -- to a point -- without maintaining a large memory footprint the rest of the time, but continuous oversubscription will keep demanding more and more memory unless you shed some of the load.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is there any way , I can avoid the **heavy** use of dynamic memory allocation? (*edit mine*)

Yes, but there are too many ways to do so than to point to a single solution.

The simplest is probably going for standard library containers, then use their `reserve` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) capabilities (or just rely on exponential growth).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

My guess is you would be looking for [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) or [unordered-map](/questions/tagged/unordered-map) to suit your needs.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Other concepts that help solve these kind of issues include [circular-buffer](/questions/tagged/circular-buffer) or [memory-pool](/questions/tagged/memory-pool)